# WSO2 Class Mediator can't able to add in pom.xml using wso2 integration studio 8.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I really fed up when working with Integation studio 8.0.0. Because of Class Mediator implementation. Project is deployed and works fine without Class Mediator. When i include this in coding and edit pom.xml by selecting Mediator, can't able to add this.

It shows ERROR like below.

[image: ERROR]

If i tried to save and deploy it into remote server which is running in my local getting below ERROR in Integration Studio.
[image: After Saving ERROR]

IntegrationStudio- ERROR DialogueBox:

[image: Integration-Studio Error]

Integration Studio ERROR:LOG:

```
java.lang.Exception: Can't find export handler for bundle
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.platform.core.project.export.util.ExportUtil.buildProject(ExportUtil.java:89)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.distribution.project.export.DefaultArtifactExportHandler.exportArtifact(DefaultArtifactExportHandler.java:37)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.distribution.project.export.CarExportHandler.exportArtifactHelper(CarExportHandler.java:130)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.distribution.project.export.CarExportHandler.exportArtifact(CarExportHandler.java:67)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.distribution.project.publisher.CAppProjectRemotePublisher.publish(CAppProjectRemotePublisher.java:48)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.carbonserver.remote.operations.ServiceModuleOperations.publishServiceModule(ServiceModuleOperations.java:152)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.carbonserver.remote.internal.RemoteCarbonServerBehavior.publishModule(RemoteCarbonServerBehavior.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publishModule(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:1093)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publishModules(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:1185)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:989)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3184)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

I am damn sure that it can be easiest thing when working with WSO2 Developer Studio.

Is this integration studio tool bug? or Am I missing anything?

Comment: Were you able to check this [documentation](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/develop/customizations/creating-custom-mediators/#!) on creating Class Mediators? Can you update the question with Integration Studio logs as well, if you have any?

Comment: Hi @Athiththan
Yes i tried the same "Mediator Project" , The only difference is that i have included Mediator under maven Multi Module Project. When i try to deploy CAR into Remote Server(running on my local machine) , nothing error shown in server/integration studio. when i trace error log in integration studio it shows like "StackTrace not available".. Please see the section "IntegrationStudio- ERROR LOG:" in above edited question.

Comment: Hi @Athiththan
getting ERROR like "java.lang.Exception: Can't find export handler for bundle" what does it mean? Please see ERROR Log above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one line of code to the Mediumor project's `pom.xml` file:

```
<properties>
    <CApp.type>lib/synapse/mediator</CApp.type>
</properties>
```

The results are as follows:

```
<name>demomediator</name>
<properties>
    <CApp.type>lib/synapse/mediator</CApp.type>
</properties>
<description>demomediator</description>
......
```

I try with https://www.fixes.pub/program/836665.html, It works fine.

Comment: Hi @simon gao,

Thanks for your response. as you said, it worked well. i added answer in some other question, forgot to add here.. FYI, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68800203/unable-to-export-project-as-deployable-archive-wso2-ei-class-mediator/68801170#68801170