# Unable to Export Project as Deployable Archive - WSO2 EI Class Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, mediator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I have created "mediator project" inside Maven Multi Module Project in the tool called "WSO2 Integration Studio 8.0.0". When i export it as a deployable artifact by right-clicking on the mediator project and selecting "Export Project as Deployable Archive" Option, i am getting below error.

[image: Integration Studio ERROR]

ERROR Log in Integration Studio:

```
!ENTRY org.wso2.integrationstudio.distribution.project 4 0 2021-08-16 14:43:30.995
!MESSAGE An error occured while creating the archive file
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception: Can't find export handler for bundle
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.platform.core.project.export.util.ExportUtil.buildProject(ExportUtil.java:89)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.distribution.project.ui.wizard.ProjectExportWizard.exportArchivable(ProjectExportWizard.java:114)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.distribution.project.ui.wizard.ProjectExportWizard.performFinish(ProjectExportWizard.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4030)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3630)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.distribution.project.ui.action.ExportProjectAction.run(ExportProjectAction.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4030)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3630)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.EventDetailsDialog.open(EventDetailsDialog.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.EventDetailsDialogAction.run(EventDetailsDialogAction.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.LogView.lambda$2(LogView.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1526)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1213)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4030)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3630)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
```

**PS:**

```
Separate Mediator Project can be bundled as Jar , Problem only with Maven Multi Module has mediator Project.
```

Kindly Help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found Solution for this. after adding below line of code in pom.xml file of Mediator Project, I can able to achieve this.

```
    <properties>
    <CApp.type>lib/synapse/mediator</CApp.type>
  </properties>
```

pom.xml:

[image: Mediator Project pom.xml file]